# Change TargetDirectory in QT Installer Framwork

Tags: qt

If user choose non-empty TargetDirectory, how I can change this line via adding subfolder?

For example, user choose in TargetDirectoryPage

```
TargetDirectoryLine = 'c:\Some'
```

I want in this case make something like

```
TargetDirectoryLineEdit.setText(targetDirLine + "/" + "ProductName")
```

and follow to install app to this folder **'c:\Some\ProductName'**.

But I do not know how catch - when I can change TargetDirectory.

IFW 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I did so:

```
Controller.prototype.ComponentSelectionPageCallback = function()
{
  var targetDir = gui.pageById(QInstaller.TargetDirectory).TargetDirectoryLineEdit.text;
  var files = QDesktopServices.findFiles(targetDir, "*.*");
  if (files.length!=0) {
    installer.setValue("TargetDir", targetDir + "\\" + installer.value("ProductName"));
  }
}
```